# Analyzing spatial distribution of invasive specie across landscape?

Tags: qgis, r, spatial-statistics, spatial-analysis

I'm studying the spatial distribution of an invasive specie introduced in a natural area.
This plant, that thrives in sunlight, grows in thickets (patches).

The population of my study site (10x10 km) was mapped using photo-interpretation.

I get polygons, each with a rate of invasion.

I'd like to understand the relative effects of several variables on its spatial distribution : open/closed area, burned areas, distance from roads and rivers, soil type and altitude.

I splatted the area into cells which have a value for each of the variables.

What kind of analysis would you do ?

I'd go for a **GLM**, using R, on the rate of invasion [0;X] in which the specie is present ~ variables.

Are there **any other approaches ?**

I work with QGIS & R.

Comment: Bayesian, least squares, standard linear, logistic, Poisson...there are many. You'll need to refine your question(s) in order to choose an appropriate regression model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the previous recommendations are solid approaches for species distribution modeling. However, an appropriate modeling approach really depends on your question and what you want. Do you want to draw inference from the model? Do you want a probabilistic estimate? Do you want to incorporate spatial process into the estimates? Do you want intensity and rate? Do you want an optimal predictor and are willing to sacrifice inference?

It sounds like you may have both count and serial data. If this is the case then none of the previously mentioned methods would be what you want. Something like a Poisson mixed effects or Point Process Model would let you account for the intensity function (counts) and the time series as a random effect (using an ARIMA term). This would let you derive risk, in the traditional sense, fairly easily. This type of model would also allow you to specify spatial autocorrelation as a random effect. Although, I would note that it is often prudent to solve Point Process Models in a Bayesian MCMC framework, particularly any model with an autoregressive term (eg., auto-logistic, CAR, SAR).

However, if you want to treat invasion as a binomial process, where a sample location either has an invasive present [1] or not [0]. Then the aforementioned models (eg., random forests, boosting, Bioclim) would work quite well and be quite straightforward to implement in R.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Actually, I'd like to :
1) understand the current distribution of this specie
2) determine the potential cells in which it could occur in a recent future.
Both at a very small scale (100 km²).
This will help to define management priorities.

Answer (score 1):

[Random Forests](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) (RF) is a very powerful ensemble learning approach for regression (and classification) that is often used with spatial data.  RF is well suited for spatial data because there are no parametric assumptions, which means that you can use binary (open/closed area, burned areas), categorical (soil type), continuous (distance from roads and rivers, altitude), or any other type of predictor variables in your analysis.

For example, using the default example in the random forest package:

```
require(randomForest)

## Regression:
## data(airquality)
set.seed(131)
ozone.rf <- randomForest(Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + Month + Day, data=airquality, mtry=3,
                         importance=TRUE, na.action=na.omit)
print(ozone.rf)
```

---

We can see the 72.31% of the variability in the model is explained when using the predictor variables Solar.R, Wind, Temp, Month, and Day.

```
> print(ozone.rf)

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Ozone ~ Solar.R + Wind + Temp + Month +      Day, data = airquality, mtry = 3, importance = TRUE, na.action = na.omit) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 3

          Mean of squared residuals: 303.8304
                    % Var explained: 72.31
>
```

---

We can also see how important each predictor variable is in explaining the response (Ozone).

```
> varImpPlot(ozone.rf)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a couple of general R-based resources for analyzing species distributions:

**Biomod2**
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biomod2/biomod2.pdf

> biomod2 offers the possibility to run 10 state-of-the-art modeling techniques to describe and model the relationships between a given species and its environment.

**Dismo**
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dismo/dismo.pdf

> This package implements a few species distribution models, including an R link to the 'maxent' model, and native implementations of Bioclim and Domain. It also provides a number of functions that can assist in using Boosted Regresssion Trees.